# Error with "SMTP end Email (V2)"

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When I select "SMTP end Email (V2)" I immediately get the error "Unable to get property 'parameters' of undefined or null reference". I know it's a preview, but I assume that it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Should be - have alerted the team.  In the future for bugs feel free to email team directly at logicappsbug[at]microsoft[dot]com